# Einstein Streaming Updates through API not working update_item_secure.json

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, api, einstein, einstein-recommendations

Apparently Salesforce is retiring the old version of streaming catalog updates this year. So they suggested we switch. I am trying to do the streaming updates for the new API call, but I'm getting a 400 error (Bad Request).

It seems pretty straightforward, but I can't even get a response using Postman.

This is my postman call (I've obscured the MID, but I assure you, it's right)[image]

There are no quotes around the items on the left, but I tried it both ways. What am I missing?

Comment: Your screen shot has your api key exposed, you can rotate this by going to reporting >> adming tools >> manage API keys and click the rotate button

Comment: Thanks @EazyE I updated the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are getting the error for one reason. In postman, your type should be JSON and not Text. this is a working example:

```
POST /c2/XXXXX/update_item_secure.json
 HTTP/1.1
Host: XXXXXX.collect.igodigital.com
Content-Type: application/json
Cookie: igodigitaltc2=0b77afa6-e7ad-11ea-9670-22770d61945a
Content-Length: 178

{
  "api_key": "XXXXXX",
  "payload": {
    "item": "123456",
    "item_type": "content",
    "name": "Name",
    "url" : "https://google.com"
  }
}
```

Comment: gah! that was it! thank you so much. I got so flustered I didn't even think to look at the headers and also, the documentation is not great on this.

Comment: any thoughts on why I'd be getting a cors error if I've whitelisted the domain?

Comment: This call isn't made to be used on a clientside (website) you would need to google cors error and possible workarounds, the whitelist domain feature was for the old client side streaming updates

Comment: ah interesting about the whitelist feature. I've been able to get ajax requests to work around CORS if I have control of the server side, but in this case I obviously don't. So perhaps I'll set up a server side page to run this call. Thanks again!

Comment: That solved my error. Additionally, for some reason it's not documented anywhere but if you want to include images in your catalogue, the parameter name is imagelink.

Comment: Yes @MilanSimic very hard to put this together because of the lack of good documentation. I've done it a few times though and I'm cobbling together the pieces for what will hopefully become a blog post one day.